# Single Authentication for different laravel web app

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to ask about authentication in Laravel.
So the case is, I have 2 apps that have correlation, among others are,

1 application is used (we call it, system A web application) for systems that process databases, such as creating blogs, editing, editing, and approving articles made by creators, and of course having login authentication to the application to process it. (https://uat-system.marsiajar.com) <- you can access it by using my username and password, email: sariayu.mahgdalena@gmail.com, and the password is h67v3km2.

1 is used again (we'll call it web application B), to preview everything generated by the system application, on this web, the system database is only used to update blogs, such as adding/editing the number of views to the blog. (https://marsiajar.com)

The correlation is, these 2 applications use 1 database that is on the server.

I want to know

**1. How do we know or show, when a user logs in to system A's web application, the user's name will appear in B's web application?**

I attached screenshots and an interface view of system A's web application,
https://ibb.co/nbW4d5c

and I attach my env's config to this,

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=marsiajarroot_uat-landingpage
DB_USERNAME=marsiajarroot_uat
DB_PASSWORD='*******'
```

this env, I used in system A's web application and in application B,

Please, does anyone, know about this?
Can we share about this?

Thank you very much for sharing ^_^

Answer (score 0):

This was on previous case before. The truth is you cannot share the cookies or session. It might be but its not the best practice. One thing i do is to use Database SESSION_DRIVER and put some variable on it (forgot the name) but as long as it is still in the same domain, i believe this thing would works.

Comment: SESSION_DOMAIN i believe, put wildcard domain on that, so it will *.masiajar.com

Comment: I will try it, mas Iting. Very helpful. Thank you mas..